# Python Pandas: Convert to 2D List of Column Headers whereas row values are not NaN

Tags: python, pandas, select, dataframe

I have this example data with row-based ranks which are calculated in a rolling window and hence being floats:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'X': [1.5, 6.777, 2.444, pd.np.NaN], 'Y': [1.111, pd.np.NaN, 8.77, pd.np.NaN], 'Z': [5.0, 2.333, 10, 6.6666]})


Out[8]: 
       X      Y        Z
0  1.500  1.111   5.0000
1  6.777    NaN   2.3330
2  2.444  8.770  10.0000
3    NaN    NaN   6.6666
```

And I want to convert it to a row-wise 2D list without NaNs, whereas instead of the real values I want to extract the column names instead; sorted by the rank.

Desired Output:

```
[[Y, X, Z], [Z, X], [X, Y, Z], [z]]
```

Furthermore I want a second output with a selection of a maximum number of values to fetch by the sorted rank. E.g. to select a maximum number of entries of 2, this would yield:

```
[[Y, X], [Z, X], [X, Y], [z]]
```

Dunno whether this is elegantly done in pandas as well. If not, no worries, than I could easily do it with a listcomprehension based on output 1 using something like:

```
 limited = [x[:2] if len(x) > 2 else x for x in OUTPUT_STEP_1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use list comprehensions with [`iterrows`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) or `transpose` DataFrame for process each row separately.

First [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), remove NaNs by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html) and get `index` to `list` (columns are converted to index, because each row is converted to `Series`).

For select only first and second value add `[]`:

```
L = [ x.sort_values().dropna().index.tolist() for idx, x in df.iterrows()]
print (L)
[['Y', 'X', 'Z'], ['Z', 'X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['Z']]

L1 = [ x.sort_values().dropna().index[:2].tolist() for idx, x in df.iterrows()]
print (L1)
[['Y', 'X'], ['Z', 'X'], ['X', 'Y'], ['Z']]
```

---

```
df1 = df.T
L = [ df1[x].sort_values().dropna().index.tolist() for x in df1]
print (L)
[['Y', 'X', 'Z'], ['Z', 'X'], ['X', 'Y', 'Z'], ['Z']]

L1 = [ df1[x].sort_values().dropna().index[:2].tolist() for x in df1]
print (L1)
[['Y', 'X'], ['Z', 'X'], ['X', 'Y'], ['Z']]
```

Comment: Cant agree more than this. Really nice.